# How can we prove that $(A \cup B) \cup C$ is the same as $A \cup (B \cup C)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I understand that $(A \cup B) \cup C$ is the same as $A \cup (B \cup C)$ intuitively. However, is there a proof for this?

Comment: Maybe see [here](https://www.easycalculation.com/theorems/associative-law.php)

Comment: Just prove that either one contains the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common method for proving that two sets are equal is to show that either one is contained in the other. That is, you want to show that:

1. $(A \cup B) \cup C \subseteq A \cup (B \cup C)$
2. $A \cup (B \cup C) \subseteq (A \cup B) \cup C$

For the first containment, suppose that $x \in (A \cup B) \cup C$. Then, either $x \in A \cup B$ or $x \in C$. Unfolding this further, gives us that $x \in A$ or $x \in B$ or $x \in C$. Thus, $x \in A$ or $x \in B \cup C$, which is exactly the definition of $x \in A \cup (B \cup C)$.

Can you fill in the detalis for the second containment?

Comment: Thank you! Filling the second containment:
` ∈  or  ∈  ∪ `, 
` ∈  or  ∈ B or  ∈ C`, 
` ∈  ∪ B or  ∈ C`, 
` ∈ (A ∪ B) ∪ C`. 

Since we can go from  `∈(∪)∪` to `∈  or ∈∪ ` which is the exact definition of  `∈∪(∪)`, do we still need to show the second containment?